# Sending/receiving ERC20 supported Tokens through web3js

Tags: tokens

I have tried a lot to connect contract with web3js function and tried alot to atleast get token name and its symbol..and sending/receiving is the next thing..But not successful..

First way:

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var address='0xd26114cd6ee289accf82350c8d8487fedb8a0c07';
var abi=[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"upgrade","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"}],"name":"setTokenInformation","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"upgradeAgent","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"upgradeMaster","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getUpgradeState","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"canUpgrade","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalUpgraded","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"agent","type":"address"}],"name":"setUpgradeAgent","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"isToken","outputs":[{"name":"weAre","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"master","type":"address"}],"name":"setUpgradeMaster","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"name":"_totalSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_decimals","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newName","type":"string"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newSymbol","type":"string"}],"name":"UpdatedTokenInformation","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Upgrade","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"agent","type":"address"}],"name":"UpgradeAgentSet","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"upgradeMaster","type":"address"}],"name":"NewUpgradeMaster","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]

var batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
batch.add(web3.eth.getBalance.request('0xA32F766fb9F23512aA122CF91bDB4eD960875CCb', 'latest'));
batch.add(new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address));
batch.execute();
```

But it shows error:

```
Error: JSONRPC method should be specified for params: "undefined"!
```

Second way:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
var abi=[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"upgrade","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"}],"name":"setTokenInformation","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"upgradeAgent","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"upgradeMaster","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getUpgradeState","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"canUpgrade","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalUpgraded","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"agent","type":"address"}],"name":"setUpgradeAgent","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"isToken","outputs":[{"name":"weAre","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"master","type":"address"}],"name":"setUpgradeMaster","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"name":"_totalSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_decimals","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newName","type":"string"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newSymbol","type":"string"}],"name":"UpdatedTokenInformation","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Upgrade","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"agent","type":"address"}],"name":"UpgradeAgentSet","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"upgradeMaster","type":"address"}],"name":"NewUpgradeMaster","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]
var token = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi),'0xd26114cd6ee289accf82350c8d8487fedb8a0c07')
token.methods.balanceOf('0x2c22e6cd1177e36497b8905298c2f5c2f3868a9f').call()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Shows Error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\pedro>node .
undefined:1
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Guide me plz

Comment: What do you get when you replace "JSON.parse(abi)" with just "abi" in the above? The error seems to point to a problem parsing the JSON - and it is already a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are almost there - these are the steps that I took in Geth; using the web3 instance that is available as part of Geth's commandline:

Create an ABI variable - similar to what you did:

```
var omiseGoAbi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"mintingFinished","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"finishMinting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_releaseTime","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintTimelocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"MintFinished","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]
```

Get a [web3 contract wrapper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) using the ABI

**Note: there is no need to parse it because it is already a JSON object.**

```
var omiseGoTokenContract = web3.eth.contract(omiseGoAbi)
```

Get an instance variable of the token contract by pointing it at the address of the token:

```
var omiseGoTokenInstance = omiseGoTokenContract.at('0xd26114cd6ee289accf82350c8d8487fedb8a0c07')
```

Call the *balanceOf* function on the token contract instance:

```
omiseGoTokenInstance.balanceOf('0x2c22e6cd1177e36497b8905298c2f5c2f3868a9f')
```

*Note: you can add the Promise logic after this call as you were doing before:*

Comment: Thanks but web3.eth.contract is not a funtion (Error says).. But when i use web3.eth.Contract  (with capital C) it get a result but that result is undefiend so calling balance or name of undefined also goes to undefined..

Comment: Oh, it looks like you're using version [1.0.0 of web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html) - which hasn't been released yet / is still in Beta. Any reason why you aren't using the stable version of web3js?

Comment: yes 1.0.0 is mine version... ok then i am going to use 0.20.0 version and then check this...

Comment: Thanks by reverting to version 0.20.0 ...its connected..But for civic token and also for other tokens it is showing 0 balance and 0 total supply and on calling name and symbol function it is showing error of                 
        BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number:

Comment: Actually i was connected to rinkeby at that time , when connected to main network problem solved..Now guide me for sending transaction for any erc20 ...As i am using this ===>                                                                               
var value = '100' // Base 10, accounts for decimals. 
token.transfer(toAddress, value, { from: addr }, function (err, txHash) {
  if (err) console.error(err)
 
  if (txHash) {
    console.log('Transaction sent')
    console.dir(txHash)
  }
})

Comment: Error:                                                                                                                      Invalid JSON RPC response: ""