# How to connect with smart contract using provider using node js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

When I am doing the following I'm getting this error:

```
var result = this.provider.send(payload);
TypeError: this.provider.send is not a function
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your provider is web3js, and there isn't a web3.send function; the documentation for the stable version of this library [can be found here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).

The current, stable version of web3js has a [web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) function.

> How to connect with smart contract using provider using node js?

If, however, you are trying to call the *send* function on a smart contract then you will need to follow [the steps similar to this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/sending-receiving-erc20-supported-tokens-through-web3js/29794#29794) to create a JS wrapper around the smart contract instance; which can be interacted with through JS function calls.